# Access Android Mobile Phone's Camera via Android TV Box

Tags: android, android-camera, wireless, android-tv

I want to design my own Android Application for access my Android Mobile Phone's Camera (Wireless and USB) via Android TV Box.

1. Should I design two Applications for Mobile and TV Box?
2. Is there any code samples?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should do it. The user interaction model for TV is substantially different from phone and tablet devices. In order to make your app successful on TV devices, you must design new layouts that can be easily understood from 10 feet away, and provide navigation that works with just a directional pad and a select button.

There is no code sample of what you want to implement. Only some basic code sample using [box-android-sdk](https://github.com/box/box-android-sdk/tree/master/box-content-sample).